# Using a predefined response ID in a GtkDialog in a GtkBuilder XML?

Tags: gtk, glade

Is there any way to use a predefined response (e.g., `GTK_RESPONSE_OK`) in a `GtkDialog`, without hard-coding the ID? Glade generates XML with "0" there by default, and gives me a numeric entry. While I suppose I could enter -5, that seems to defeat the point of having a constant.

The Glade XML looks like this:

```
<action-widgets>
  <action-widget response="0">cancel-button</action-widget>
  <action-widget response="0">connect-button</action-widget>
</action-widgets>
```

Even [the example in the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-BUILDER-UI):

```
<action-widgets>
  <action-widget response="3">button_ok</action-widget>
  <action-widget response="-5">button_cancel</action-widget>
</action-widgets>
```

(Which is a bit hilarious, given that they're using -5 (`GTK_RESPONSE_OK`) for "`button_cancel`"…)

Comment: I don't know if there is, but if it doesn't, this looks like feature request material.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725810/glade-3-standard-button-layout

Answer (score 1):

Since GTK 3.12 you can use nck-names for the response.

```
commit baa471ec130c360a5c4ae314769bc7b858814219
Author: Jasper St. Pierre <jstpierre@mecheye.net>
Date:   Mon Oct 28 11:19:43 2013 -0400

  gtkdialog: Allow specifying response IDs by nick in <action-widgets>

  This makes it a lot more convenient for developers, as they don't
  have to look up the numeric value of response IDs.
```

so you can now do

```
<action-widgets>
  <action-widget response="ok">button_ok</action-widget>
  <action-widget response="cancel">button_cancel</action-widget>
</action-widgets>
```